# How to ban all executable files on Apache

Tags: php, security, apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to find out the most effective way to ban any executable files from one specific sub folder on my server. I allow file uploads by users into that folder, and would like to make that folder accessible from the web. I have the root folder pretty much locked down with mod_rewrite. In that one unprotected sub-folder I have .htaccess with:

```
Options +Indexes  
IndexOptions +FancyIndexing +FoldersFirst +HTMLTable  
RewriteEngine off
```

I know it is best to just restrict file uploads to a certain allowable file types, and I am already doing this in php. I am checking file extension, and mime type before allowing an upload like this:

```
$allmime=array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'application/msword', 'application/pdf');
$allext=array('png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'doc', 'pdf');
$path=pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
$mime=trim(shell_exec("file -bi " . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
if( !in_array( $path['extension'], $allext) || !in_array($mime, $allmime) ){
    //ban
}else{
    //allow
}
```

However I am not certain if there is some convoluted hack out there that will still allow a shell script to be uploaded and executed on the server, since all of the successfully uploaded files will be visible immediately.

I know there is another option in .htaccess to filter out files like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(sh|asp|cgi|php|php3|ph3|php4|ph4|php5|ph5|phtm|phtml)$">
    order allow, deny
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

However I am not certain that this list is all-inclusive, plus this is hard to maintain, as new extensions might be installed in the future.

To sum it all up: Anyone knows a good way to disallow all server executables, with the exception of php scripts directly executed by the `%{HTTP_HOST}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about disabling the server-side handlers for that specific directory?  Something like:

```
<Directory /path/to/restrict>
    SetHandler None
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

This is untested, but seems like it might work.

**UPDATE**: Apparently, I was wrong ... but sticking `AddHandler default-handler` in an `.htaccess` *does* seem to work.

Comment: Using the `AddHandler default-handler` or using `AddType text/html` is probably the best way to control script execution. This way I am not relying on mime check and file extension check alone. I have done some limited testing with php code embedded in a gif file. Mime check does not stop the upload. If I would not verify the extension, then this gifimg.php file would upload just fine. Without AddHandler or AddType directive this file would execute. I could rely on file extension check, but it does not give assurance that my allowable extensions will never be associated with any apache mod.

Answer (score 2):

You can do several things to absolutely lock down certain folders to ensure PHP is not able to execute in them, particularly useful if doing a PHP upload script and you don't want the world to be able to execute arbitrary code on your server by exploiting your upload code:

- disable the PHP engine entirely in .htaccess for the folder in question:

```js
  php_flag engine off
```

- force the Content-Disposition header to attachment for files that are not of a finite list of file types you are expecting, for example:

```js
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
  <FilesMatch "(?i)\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
    ForceType none
    Header unset Content-Disposition
  </FilesMatch>
```

- prevent uploading of files with any extension which can be executed by an Apache module like PHP directly in your uploader code

Comment: These are brilliant ways to provide extra protections for an upload folder... just a minor tweak, can you correct the spelling of "Dispositon" on line 2 :-)

Answer (score 1):

From twitter's bootstrapper .htaccess, this works for me (just added exe):

```
# Block access to backup and source files.
# These files may be left by some text editors and can pose a great security
# danger when anyone has access to them.

<FilesMatch "(^#.*#|\.(exe|bak|config|dist|fla|inc|ini|log|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

Results in:

**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access /test/test.exe on this server.

Answer (score 0):

The best way (imo) is just to turn off the x in the subfolder (executable permission in linux).  So I would change the permissions to 644 (logged in you can read and write, but the world can only read).  This can be done in cpanel.  Make sure to apply that to sub folders as well.

Comment: Sorry dude, but my files are already 644, plus any PHP script will execute just fine with 444.

Comment: Well then your good, the files can't be executed by anyone, even if they are executable files

Comment: No, I am not good, I am screwed! If a PHP file has read only permission, it means that a PHP interpretor will have access to it, and subsequently will be able to process it.

Comment: yes, but to run the file you would need access to run the php interpreter, something they don't have access to.

Comment: I would suggest you read (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) Since PHP is a server side scripting language, any HTTP request for a world-readable php file would signal the server to pass the request to php interpreter, which in turn will read and parse the script. Any page visitor can request to view a php file. Luckily they see the result, after it has been parsed.

Comment: Why would you possibly store the **user uploaded** file in the public_html directory?

Comment: That is why you use a php script with a database backend.  Store the file in the database, and stream it through a php script (using headers).

Comment: This is where I learned it: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Filtering by the uploaded filename is how malicious users will get bad things on to your server. The $_FILES name and type attributes are user supplied data and nothing says a user can't upload a PHP script but call it 'puppies.jpg'

Proper way to filter is to use something like Fileinfo and check actual MIME types and filter on that

Comment: Thanks, but I am already doing it in my example. I am checking mime and file extension. Plus fileinfo() is not reliable, I am using shell command instead. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I thought I needed to explain why mime/extension check is insufficient. Here are two articles explaining why mime check can be easily bypassed [[link1](http://www.scanit.be/uploads/php-file-upload.pdf)] and [[link2](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat.htm)]. Doing getimagesize(), exif_imagetype(), imagepng() would have been sufficient if I did not need document (pdf, doc,...) uploads as well.

Answer (score 0):

Deny complete access to folder in an .htaccess file, and then use a download script to download the file, would save a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html)

The following rule will forbid .exe (i added .bat) files from being downloaded from your server:

```
<Directory "/my/files">
    Require all granted
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule "(\.exe|\.bat)" "-" [F]
</Directory>
```